# change methods to widgets dynamically in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to Qt and I try to iterate on 10 controls and show/hide them.

```
switch (id)
{
 case 1:
    ui->lblSinglePulse1->hide();
    ui->pbSinglePulse1->hide();
    break;
case 2:
    ui->lblSinglePulse2->hide();
    ui->pbSinglePulse2->hide();
    break;
case 3:
    ui->lblSinglePulse3->hide();
    ui->pbSinglePulse3->hide();
    break;
case 4:
... and so on
```

I am sure there is another way to  pass the widget name dynamically.
for example: 
ui->getWidgetByName("lblSinglePulse" + "2" )->hide();
or somthing else...

please your help.

Comment: Use arrays or lists or vectors of widgets.

Comment: Or an id to widget map/hash

Comment: can you give me a small example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by **@Mat** comment

You need add all controls to list first, like this

```
lblSinglePulseList.append(ui->lblSinglePulse1);
lblSinglePulseList.append(ui->lblSinglePulse2);
lblSinglePulseList.append(ui->lblSinglePulse3);
...
pblSinglePulseList.append(ui->pblSinglePulse1);
pblSinglePulseList.append(ui->pblSinglePulse2);
pblSinglePulseList.append(ui->pblSinglePulse3);
```

Then use list in your function

```
lblSinglePulseList[id - 1]->hide();
pblSinglePulseList[id - 1]->hide();
```

Edited:

If type of ui->lblSinglePulse1 is **Lable** and type of ui->pbSinglePulse1 is **PushButton**, then list init is:

```
QList<Lable *> lblSinglePulseList;
QList<PushButton *> pblSinglePulseList;
```

Comment: what should be the type of lblSinglePulseList ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with a map like this:

Header file.

```
class YourClass
{
public:
    // ...

private:
    void setHidden( const int aIndex, const bool aHidden );
    void setAllVisible();

private:
    QMap< int, QList< QWidget* > > m_Widgets; // This shall be a member of your class.
};
```

Source file.

```
YourClass::YourClass()
{
    m_Widgets[ 0 ] << ui->lblSinglePulse1;
    m_Widgets[ 0 ] << ui->pblSinglePulse1;
    m_Widgets[ 1 ] << ui->lblSinglePulse2;
    m_Widgets[ 1 ] << ui->pblSinglePulse3;
    // And so ...
}

// To hide widgets at a given index.
void YourClass::setHidden( const int aIndex, const bool aHidden)
{
    // First you need to set all items visible otherwise the result won't be the desired ... I think.
    setAllVisible();

    for ( auto item : m_Widgets[ aIndex ] )
    {
        item->setHidden( aHidden );
    }
}

void YourClass::setAllVisible()
{
    for ( auto items : m_Widgets )
    {
        for ( auto item : items )
        {
            item->setVisible( true );
        }
    }
}
```